# Is there a Mill "Run Configuration" for IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, mill

I'm trying to figure out how to create a "Run Configuration" for a Scala Mill project.

There are entries for Maven and SBT, but nothing for Mill. There doesn't seem to be a "Mill" plugin for IntelliJ either.

I create a Scala Mill project with this command:

```sh
mill mill.scalalib.GenIdea/idea
```

And install the Build Server Protocol:

```sh
mill mill.bsp.BSP/install
```

Is it best just to make a "Shell Script" configuration that runs `mill foo.run`?

[image: IntelliJ Run Configuration]